# install packages to each servers in amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need 20 instances on EC2 with the same configuration and packages installed. 
I'm doing these one by one. But how could I install the packages to each servers at once?
I couldn't figure it out in amazon doc.

Comment: Offtopic. Server deployment/configuration is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon doesn't offer any tools itself to do something like this.  You would need to set up your own approach to doing something like this.  There are various options depending on what you want to do or what your requirements are, some of which include:

- You could install something like [pssh](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) which would let you run SSH commands in parallel across multiple servers.
- You could install a configuration management system like [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/), [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-open-source), etc. and use it to provision all your systems.
- Install everything you want on a single instance, then [create an AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html) from that instance, and use that AMI to spin up all the other instances.

Each of those approaches has advantages & disadvantages.  Installing pssh is pretty straightforward.  Setting up something like ansible & puppet takes a fair amount of initial configuration but then makes management of systems very easy & powerful.  Building an AMI isn't terribly difficult but if you realize you made a mistake in your image after the fact then you either need to fix it manually on all your instances or build a new AMI & redeploy all your instances.

Comment: Wow! impressive guidance

Answer (score 0):

@Bruce P correctly stated that *Amazon* does not offer any approach to install packages in all instances. However, I would like to mention the existence of *Amazon*'s *EMR*, if it could somehow be used in your case.

*Amazon*'s *Elastic MapReduce* provides a bootstraping functionality that allows users to run a custom code, such as a bash script, in order to configure the instance in a custom way.

This functionality allowed me the installation of a custom library that was essential on my *MapReduce* job.